# What do I need to do to change the size and color of the object with D3.js?

Tags: d3.js, observablehq

Please see the code in Observablehq notebook: https://observablehq.com/@erayalan/radial-scatter-plot

I am trying to understand how I can change the size and color of each item within this piece:

```
data = [{ name : "foo", r: 40, theta: 1.4 }, 
        { name : "bar", r: 30, theta: 4.8 }, 
        { name : "baz", r: 60, theta: 3.05}]
```

Comment: First, your link is broken. Second, there are no such things in SVG like __size__ and __color__. You have `fill` and `stroke` for colors; `width` and `height` for <rect>, `r` for <circle>, `points` for <polygon> and so on... So please ask a more focused question :)

Comment: Thank you for caring to respond to my potentially dumb question. I am no developer and trying to figure out things with half understanding. I updated the link hopefully it makes it clear what I am trying to accomplish. Specifically, I am trying to understand how I can change the size and color of each item within this piece: data = [{ name : "foo", r: 40, theta: 1.4 },
        { name : "bar", r: 30, theta: 4.8 },
        { name : "baz", r: 60, theta: 3.05}]

Answer (score 0):

To change the size of the circles, you can use the `"r"` property, similar to how you are doing with the "cx" and "cy". I assume you want to map "theta" to size. First you need to create [a scale](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#linear-scales):

```js
  const radiusScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain(d3.extent(data, d=> d.theta)).range([10, 20])
```

The function [extent](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#extent) in `d3.extent(data, d=> d.theta)` returns the maximum and minimum values of your data in the theta property (in this case, `[1.4, 4.8]`). That means this scale has a domain of `[1.4, 4.8]` and a range of `[10, 20]`, so if you call `radiusScale(1.4)` it will output `10`, and `radiusScale(4.8)` will output `20`. With this, you mapped the theta value to an adequate radius, and can use it on the `"r"` property of the SVG circle:

```js
  .attr("cx", d => d.r * Math.cos(d.theta))
  .attr("cy", d => d.r * Math.sin(d.theta))
  .attr("r", d => radiusScale(d.theta))
```

A similar logic applies to color, which is defined in the `"fill"` property. You want to map the "foo", "bar", and "baz" to different colors. You can use the `scaleOrdinal` and a color array for this:

```js
   const colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(d3.schemeCategory10)
```

The range of this scale is `d3.schemeCategory10`, which is simply an array that contains some common colors (you can use any array of colors). You don't need a domain for this scale, because d3 can automatically assign a different color for each unique value the scale receives.

Then you can complement the mapping, assigning the color to the fill property.

```js
  .attr("cx", d => d.r * Math.cos(d.theta))
  .attr("cy", d => d.r * Math.sin(d.theta))
  .attr("r", d => radiusScale(d.theta))
  .attr("fill", d => colorScale(d.name))
```

Here is [a fork of your notebook](https://observablehq.com/@rodrigodivino/radial-scatter-plot) with the changes above:

### Side notes:

In my answer, I mapped the value of theta directly to the radius. It is not recommended to use the radius of a circle to encode a value, the best practice is to use its area. I'll not go into depth here for the sake of simplicity, but you can check better ways of mapping size [here](https://bl.ocks.org/guilhermesimoes/e6356aa90a16163a6f917f53600a2b4a).

The learning curve of D3 can be little steep. You saw several concepts in this answer to change the color and size (scales, domains, ranges, extents, and more!). You might want to check [the official d3 introduction](https://observablehq.com/@d3/learn-d3) to see these concepts in a more sequential manner.

Comment: This is fantastic Rodrigo. Thank you. I will check out the tutorials.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a snippet with sizes and colors:

```js
data = [
  {name: "foo", r: 40, theta: 1.4, size: 10, color: 'red'},
  {name: "bar", r: 30, theta: 4.8, size: 12, color: 'green'},
  {name: "baz", r: 60, theta: 3.05, size: 14, color: 'blue'}
];

const width = 200;
const height = 200;
const svg = d3.select('svg');

const radius = 100;
const r = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, 1])
      .range([0, radius]);

svg
  .attr("viewBox", `${-width / 2} ${-height / 2} ${width} ${height}`)
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)
  .style("font", "10px sans-serif");

const gr = svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'r axis')
  .selectAll('g')
  .data(r.ticks(5).slice(1))
  .enter()
  .append('g');

gr.append('circle')
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "#ebebeb")
  .attr('r', r);

const ga = svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'a axis')
  .selectAll('g')
  .data(d3.range(0, 360, 30)) // line density
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', d => 'rotate(' + -d + ')');

 ga.append('line')
   .attr("fill", "none")
   .attr("stroke", "#aaa")
   .attr('x2', radius);
  
 svg.selectAll("point") // No longer "rect"
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", d => d.r * Math.cos(d.theta))
  .attr("cy", d => d.r * Math.sin(d.theta))
  .attr("r", d => d.size)
  .style('stroke', d => d.color)
  .style('fill', 'white');

  svg.selectAll("text") // Note "text", not "circle" or "rect"
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .text(d => d.name)
  .attr("x", d => d.r * Math.cos(d.theta))
  .attr("y", d => d.r * Math.sin(d.theta))
  .attr('alignment-baseline', 'middle')
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
  .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
  .attr("font-size", "11px")
  .attr("fill", d => d.color);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg/>
```

Comment: And, of course, an excellent answer of Rodrigo is also very helpful :)

Comment: Applied this one and works like a charm. Thank you very much, Michael.